# Install ubuntu-desktop

Tags: apt

I am a complete newbie to Ubuntu. I just took over looking after a machine that is running 13.04. The machine does not have a GUI that I can find. How do I install something like ubuntu-desktop or xwindows with all required dependencies?
I tried (from root) "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" and I received more than a screen full of dependencies. Is thee a way to get xwindows/desktop installed with one command?

Comment: Jan 27 2014 was the EOL of the Ubuntu server that you are looking after. As it is a server it does not have the desktop features.

Comment: Is there an upgrade path or do I need to do a fresh install and an app migration?

Comment: 13.04 is **beyond ancient** and has not had any support since 20.14.  There is no real upgrade path available from there other than a fresh install and app migrations.  You WILL have problems going from such old apps to brand new apps though, some will need updates and upgrades and others will need rewritten.